# Converting CMTime values to swift

Tags: ios, swift, cmtime

I have the following 2 lines of code that I am moving to Swift but I am a little stuck.

```
CMTime trimmingTime = CMTimeMake(lround(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale / videoAsset.nominalFrameRate), videoAsset.naturalTimeScale);
CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(trimmingTime, CMTimeSubtract(videoAsset.timeRange.duration, trimmingTime));
```

When converting the below line to begin with I get the following error.

```
var trimmingTime: CMTime
trimmingTime = CMTimeMake(value: lround(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale / videoAsset.nominalFrameRate), timescale: videoAsset.naturalTimeScale)
```

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'CMTimeScale' (aka 'Int32') and 'Float'

I have tried a few different approaches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672908/how-to-pass-float-in-cmtimemakes-timescale-int32/51674952#51674952 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not simply perform mathematically operation with different type of operands in swift like other languages. You need to type-cast manually.

Here you should cast `videoAsset.naturalTimeScale`( which is `CMTimeScale` and CMTimeScale is of type `Int32`) to Float to get it work.

```
Float(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale)
```

But `CMTimeMake`'s value key will accept value `CMTimeValue` type value. So use it like:

```
trimmingTime = CMTimeMake(value: CMTimeValue(Float(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale) / videoAsset.nominalFrameRate), timescale: videoAsset.naturalTimeScale)
```

Again to make you code more Swifty use `CMTime` rather `CMTimeMake` as:

```
trimmingTime = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(Float(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale) / videoAsset.nominalFrameRate), timescale: videoAsset.naturalTimeScale)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CMTimeScale' (aka 'Int32') and 'Float' so you need forecast CMTimeScale into Float.

You need to convert `CMTimeScale` into `Float`:

```
trimmingTime = CMTimeMake(value: lround(Float(videoAsset.naturalTimeScale) / videoAsset.nominalFrameRate), timescale: videoAsset.naturalTimeScale)
```